# Умножение цены вариативных товаров Woocommerce на курс

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, woocommerce, веб-сайт

Меняю цены на сайте из RUB в BYN, товары спарсили в российских рублях. Это помогло решить проблему с обычными товарами:

```
function my_woocommerce_get_price($price, $_product) {
    $kurs = 0.039; 
    $new_price = $price * $kurs;
    return $new_price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_get_price',100,2);
```

Не могу найти решение для вариативных товаров. Все доступные решения либо не работают, либо же при добавлении товара в корзину показывают старые цены. Кто-нибудь сталкивался может с подобным и знает, как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Помог простой плагин Exchange Rates Today.

Comment: Как именно он помог, добавьте подробности, иначе это комментарий, а не качественный ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Прощу прощения. Установил плагин. Вкладка в админ-панели Woocommerce - "Курс сегодня". После перехода появляется поле, в котором вводишь число (множитель курса). Ввёл необходимое число и сохранил изменения. Всё. Теперь вариативные товары имеют нормальную цену, согласно установленному курсу и добавляются в корзину.

Comment: Ответ отредактируй, а не в комментах объясняй.